# Why Python recursive function returns None

Tags: python

The following code returns `None` on some values (eg `306, 136`), on some values (`42, 84`), it returns the answer correctly.  The `print a` and `return a` should yield the same result, but it does not:

```
def gcdIter (a,b):
    c = min (a,b)
    d = max (a,b)
    a = c
    b = d

    if (b%a) == 0:
        print a
        return a
    gcdIter (a,b%a)    


print gcdIter (a,b)
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 8):

You are ignoring the return value for the recursive call:

```
gcdIter (a,b%a)
```

Recursive calls are no different from calls to other functions; you'd still need to do something with the result of that call if that is what you tried to produce. You need to pass on that return value with `return`

```
return gcdIter (a,b%a)
```

Note that you can assign to multiple targets when assigning:

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    a, b = min(a, b), max(a, b)
    if b % a == 0:
        return a
    return gcdIter(a, b % a)
```

You really don't need to care about the bigger and smaller values here. A more compact version would be:

```
def gcd_iter(a, b):
    return gcd_iter(b, a % b) if b else abs(a)
```