# Last list returned from a method printing nonetype object in python

Tags: python

I have a recursive algorithm which needs to be able to return a list of lists.

If I print the lists remaining I get many lists which are different until we get to the last one. then I can't return the last list.

Here's my code:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[], result = []):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target:
        result.append(partial)
    if s >= target and len(numbers) == 1:
        print(result)
        print(type(result))
        return result

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], result)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(subset_sum([3,9,8,4,5,7,10],15))
```

And here's the output:

```
[]                                                                      
<class 'list'>                                                          
[]                                                                      
<class 'list'>                                                          
[]                                                                      
<class 'list'>                                                          
[]                                                                      
<class 'list'>                                                          
[]                                                                      
<class 'list'>                                                          
[]                                                                      
<class 'list'>                                                          
[]                                                                      
<class 'list'>                                                          
[]
```

(etc)

```
<class 'list'>
[[3, 8, 4], [3, 5, 7], [8, 7]]
<class 'list'>
[[3, 8, 4], [3, 5, 7], [8, 7]]
<class 'list'>
None
```

As you can see it does do what I want it to do, and even though it produces a list at the end it can't be returned.

Any way. Thank you  in advance for your help. All help is appreciated :)

Comment: You are not returning any value after your for loop.

Comment: If the code makes it to the for loop, you aren't returning anything.  Perhaps the last line of the function should be `return subset_sum(...)`?

Comment: Not really.  The idea is to go through the recursion tree and only return on certain conditions. So it doesn't really need to return unless it returns which it does.

Comment: If you make it to the for loop and call the function again, and _that_ call returns something, you will lose that returned value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Python recursive function returns None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221826/why-python-recursive-function-returns-none)

Comment: Take note that your function is not pure - ``partial`` and ``result`` persist between calls. This creates wrong results when calling the function multiple times. Initialise new lists when the parameters are not set, instead of having unique default lists.

Answer (score 0):

A `return` statement only returns its value to the calling scope. When nesting function calls, the leaf function can only return a value to the root if all intermediate functions `return` as well:

```
>>> def do_return(call, *args):
...     return call(*args)

>>> def donot_return(call, *args):
...     call(*args)
...
>>> do_return(do_return, do_return, do_return, lambda: 5)
5
>>> do_return(do_return, donot_return, do_return, lambda: 5)
None
```

In a recursive function, this means that every recursive path must return.

---

In your case, upon reaching the `for` loop nothing is returned every again. This means none of the nested recursive calls can return a value to the root of your calls. A simple approach is to check whether the recursive call returned a meaningful value:

```
    ...
    found = subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], result)
    if found is not None:
        return found
```

Alternatively, use an exception.

However, your approach is not recursing consistently - you modify the same `result = []` list on each step. Either use a pure function which does not modify its input but returns a result, or modify and return the result directly.

```
    ...
    subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], result)
return result
```

A working recursive approach looks like this:

```
def subset_sum(numbers: list, target: int, split=0) -> list:
    """
    :param numbers: set of numbers to search for subsets
    :param target: the desired subset sum to search for
    :param split: index at which to split subsequences
    """
    total = sum(numbers)
    if total == target:
        return [numbers]
    elif total < target:
        return []
    else:
        results = []
        for i in range(split, len(numbers)):
            remaining = numbers[:i] + numbers[i+1:]
            results.extend(subset_sum(remaining, target, i))
        return results


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(subset_sum([3, 9, 8, 4, 5, 7, 10], 15))
# [[5, 10], [8, 7], [3, 5, 7], [3, 8, 4]]
```

Notably, *every* path returns a valid result (even if it is empty). This means that no result is dropped. In addition, returning values is the only way to move information to the caller - no shared data is modified.